# How can I efficiently import css values into javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I have a `colors.less` file that maintains consistent color palette for a site.

I also have a `chart.js` file that requires hard coded colors to display chart elements in appropriate colors.

How can I make the chart colors dependent on the generated `colors.css` file?

So far I've been maintaining two color palettes, one in `less` and another in `js`. How can I merge the two?

Example:

```
/* colors.less */
@green:    #46a546;
@red:      #9d261d;
@yellow:   #f1c40f;
```

and

```
/* chart.js */
var chartElements = {
    "apples": {
        label: "Apples",
        color: "#46a546",
    },
    "oranges": {
        label: "Oranges",
        color: "#f1c40f",
    },
    "grapes": {
        label: "Grapes",
        color: "#9d261d",
    }...
```

How can I stop maintaining both sets of colors?

Comment: build script or set values to elements and read the elements in JavaScript.

Comment: There is no (easy) way LESS can read your JS, so do it in the other way: read CSS from JS, just like here (i find my comment to short to be an answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362445/passing-less-variable-to-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having that exact problem, I "solved" it with the following hack.

1. The CSS includes a list of "swatch-nn" classes (`swatch-1`, `swatch-2`, and so on).  Those get the pre-defined LESS constants as their background color. (For me, a simple numerically-ordered list works; other situations might call for other approaches.)
2. My SPA wrapper creates a (hidden) list of elements that have the swatch classes.

   ```
   <div id=swatches>
     <div class=swatch-1>
     <div class=swatch-2>
     <!-- etc -->
   </div>
   ```
3. Some JavaScript code at application startup populates a globally-available list of colors from the swatches.

   ```
   var swatches = {}, $swatchContainer = $("#swatches"), rname = /\bswatch-(.*)\b/;

   $swatchContainer.children("div").each(function() {
       var swatch = this;
       this.className.replace(rname, function(_, label) {
           swatches[label] = $(swatch).css("backgroundColor");
       });
   })

   $.swatches = swatches;
   ```

My Chart.js code thus copies the color values out of that global array. It's crude but it works fine.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in your DOM, you have a set of hidden objects colored by your LESS, named `swatch-nn`. Then you can reference these at any time using js? ... Edit: I see you're editing your answer. I'll be patient and let you fill in the gaps. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan yes - I just added the code I actually use to fetch the background colors at startup time.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, I started with your solution, but found that I could dynamically add and remove elements as necessary and keep my `html` clean. So the `js` can just reference the class name like so: `$("<span>").addClass(className).appendTo(document).css("background-color");`. My actual solution is a bit more involved, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Even tho Pointy's answer may fit better here (talking about LESS), I want to remind that you can access *stylesheet* data directly via ECMAscript. You might be able to identify a specific rule and just grab the value. Might look like

```
[].forEach.call(document.styleSheets, function( set ) {
  if( set.href && set.href.indexOf( 'dialog.css' ) > -1 ) {
    [].forEach.call( set.cssRules, function( rule ) {
      if( rule.selectorText === 'div#dialog-container-left' ) {
        // to whatever here, grab the value and store it for global application usage
        console.log( rule.style.backgroundColor );
      }
    });
  }
});
```